# Correct location of self created module in React project

Tags: reactjs

I've created my own implementation of "react-router",
using some Typescript.

I would like to know where is it considered the right location for such implementation(s) inside my React project structure ?

Putting this code in my Components folder seems somehow incorrect.

Appreciate your advise.

Comment: Why did you use your own implementation react-router types? The most popular router library for React has official types: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/react-router but if you want to use your own types for libraries you could make new .d.ts file of files and declare there some types - even on root of project.

Comment: Can you please post your code?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask